# Java - REST webtraget queryParam from Map

Tags: java, rest

I'm trying to create an `WebTartget` with some queryParameters. I've got a method which has `Map<String, ?> queryParams` as parameter. Inside a for loop of the map's keySet I'm trying to add the parameters to the `WebTarget`.

```
 WebTarget webTarget = createTarget(target);
 for (String key : queryParams.keySet()) {
     webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(key, queryParams.get(key));
 }

 return webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer ".concat(this.getKeycloakAccessToken()))
        .get(resultType);
```

The problem is, that the decompiled .class file looks like this:

```
for (String key : queryParams.keySet()) {
    webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(key, new Object[]{queryParams.get(key)});
}
```

If I evaluate the code in Intellij my query contains this:
`&deviceNumbers=2&deviceNumbers=3`

But if I execute the code my query contains this instead:
`&deviceNumbers=%5BLjava.lang.String%3B%404b887c24`

In this example a String array is passed inside the queryParam Map.

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround I've used:

```
private WebTarget setQueryParams(WebTarget webTarget, Map<String, Object> queryParams) {

    if (queryParams != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : queryParams.entrySet()) {
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            if (value instanceof Iterable) {
                for (Object o : ((Iterable) value)) {
                    webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(entry.getKey(), o);
                }
            } else if (value.getClass().isArray()) {
                webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(entry.getKey(), (Object[]) value);
            } else {
                webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(entry.getKey(), value);
            }
        }
    }

    return webTarget;
}
```

The problem was that the compiler created an `Object[]` which contained my `String[]`. Now I simply cast my array to an `Object[]` so this problem wont occur anymore. For all classes that implements `Iterable` like `List` or `Set` I manually add the query parameter as often as needed.